# Android gallery pick like Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, whatsapp

This question has been asked before but I'm afraid answers might be outdated.
How can I use the native gallery app (say API 14 on) to achieve multiple image selection like WhatsApp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None worked, so I ended up using one of the open source libraries for Android: [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Answer (score 0):

do you mean:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
```

Note: the EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE option is only available in Android API 18 and higher.

This link talks about [creating custom image picker with multiple select.](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)

Comment: did you try the answer that i posted ?